# Old Bitcoin QT Core (V0.7) - Sent BTC - Lost?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I performed a 'Send Bitcoin' transaction from my really old Bitcoin QT Core client (V0.7 2-beta) a few days ago as a Test. 
The client is YEARS out of date regarding the Blockchain.

I can see the Transaction Status on the client about an hour after sending it was given as -->

*"Status: 0/unconfirmed, broadcast through 28 nodes".*

I sent the nominal BTC transaction to an address beginning with "1B.." a legacy BTC address. There was a Transaction fee added natively by the Client (0.0005 BTC).

I’ve got a BTC **Transaction ID** for the Send BTC - but it is not showing up on blockchain.info, after 2 or 3 days now.. ?

- Anyone know what might be the problem ?

ps - If this is a hopeless scenario - is there anywhere I could reverse that transaction ?

Understand a Core Client Upgrade would be the way to go - but I was just checking if I could so a Send (as a Tester), to save me all the time to get my setup up to date, download 145gig etc..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone know what might be the problem ?

Your client thinks that funds were sent. All other nodes know nothing about your transaction. So, the truth is that your bitcoins are still yours, but you should remove the unconfirmed transaction from your wallet and/or use updated software.

Comment: How would I remove the unconfirmed transaction from my wallet ? Thanks